# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.3

```
class Store extends AppModel {
    var $useTable = 'store';
    var $belongsTo = array(
        'Employee' => array(
            'className' => 'Employee',
            'foreignKey' => 'employee_store'
             )
    ); 
    }
```

Controller

```
public function index(){ 
$options=array(             
        'joins' =>
                  array(
                    array(
                        'table' => 'Employee',
                        'alias' => 'Employee',
                        'foreignKey' => true,
                        'conditions'=> array('Employee.employee_store = Store.store_name')
                    )

));
$coupons = $this->Store->find('all', $options);
}
```

I am getting error SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias .

Query is displaying like below

```
SELECT `Store`.`id`,
       `Store`.`store_name`,
       `Store`.`store_address`,
       `Store`.`store_phone`,
       `Store`.`store_email`,
       `Store`.`store_website`,
       `Store`.`date_enter`,
       `Store`.`store_shortcode`,
       `Employee`.`id`,
       `Employee`.`employee_name`,
       `Employee`.`employee_phone`,
       `Employee`.`employee_email`,
       `Employee`.`employee_username`,
       `Employee`.`employee_password`,
       `Employee`.`employee_store`,
       `Employee`.`date_enter`
FROM `billing`.`store` AS `Store`
LEFT JOIN `billing`.`employee` AS `Employee` ON (`Store`.`employee_id` = `Employee`.`id`)
JOIN `billing`.`Employee` AS `Employee` ON (`Employee`.`employee_store` = `Store`.`store_name`)
WHERE 1 = 1
```

Comment: you use $hasMany instead of $belongsTo $this->Store->find('all'); there is no need to joining query becase hasmany aleready join your query

Comment: i need to join store_name with employee_store(store_name=employee_store) . but current its joining  store_name with id (store_name=id).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to unbindModel because you are already bind `Employee` model in `Store` model that's why it conflict with your Model.

```
public function index(){ 
  $this->Store->unbindModel(
        array('belongsTo' => array('Employee')), true
    );

$options=array(             
        'joins' =>
                  array(
                    array(
                        'table' => 'Employee',
                        'alias' => 'Employee',
                        'foreignKey' => true,
                        'conditions'=> array('Employee.employee_store = Store.store_name')
                    )    
));
  $coupons = $this->Store->find('all', $options);
}
```

Comment: Error:Call to a member function unbindModel() on a non-object

Comment: Try to put `true` in this line `array('belongsTo' => array('Employee')), true` check in updated answer

Comment: same error : Call to a member function unbindModel() on a non-object .Is it needed to change something in AppModel or Store ...

Comment: Comment this code in Store model `var $belongsTo = array(
        'Employee' => array(
            'className' => 'Employee',
            'foreignKey' => 'employee_store'
             )
    ); `

Comment: Its displaying only store columns , I need to display both store and employee columns also ..

Comment: Can you ask `New Question` so I can Explain well.

Comment: question limit is reached. So mail me wvswvs4@gmail.com.

Comment: Ask new question with your new problem so I can easily explain you

Comment: can u explain me how to display other columns